# ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric ~* unknown

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to created `domain` in PostgreSQL for a price. The price must be `NUMERIC(9,2)` where 9 is precision and 2 - scale. When trying to create domain getting:

`ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric ~* unknown`
`Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

**QUERY:**

```
CREATE DOMAIN d_price AS NUMERIC(9, 2) NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT Product_price_can_contain_only_double_precision_value
CHECK(VALUE ~*'^(([[:digit:]])+\.([[:digit:]]){2})$');
```

Comment: Cast your numeric to TEXT. Eg. `(VALUE::TEXT ~ '^(([[:digit:]])+\.([[:digit:]]){2})$')`. You do not need the case-insensitive symbole (`*`) either. More details at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: What's the use of the check constraint? That does not make any sense. A `numeric` column won't let you store non-numeric values anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I need numeric value in specific form, something like: `[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}` . Ex: `25.10` ; `199999.00`

Comment: Agree with @a_horse_with_no_name -- numbers do not have a format except when converted to text in a particular way. The constraint does nothing.

Comment: I think this might be a case of trying to define a number in terms of text, when range may be a better option. What is the min and max value of this numeric? A range check constraint makes much more sense for a number. Would that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your numeric value as a string before you can use the string operator, change your `VALUE` to: `CAST(VALUE AS TEXT)`

Comment: For those who use it with JPA, you can use CAST(VALUE AS string).

Answer (score 4):

Your `CHECK` constraint is nonsensical, because it applies *after* the value has already been converted to `NUMERIC` by the database engine's number parser.

```
VALUE ~*'^(([[:digit:]])+\.([[:digit:]]){2})$')
```

appears to say "one or more leading digits, a period, and exactly two trailing digits". You can't do that check in any useful way once the number has already been parsed. Observe:

```
regress=> SELECT NUMERIC(18,2) '1', NUMERIC(18,2) '1.12345';
 numeric | numeric 
---------+---------
    1.00 |    1.12
(1 row)
```

No matter what the input is, if it fits inside the `NUMERIC` you've specified, it'll be extended to fit. If it doesn't fit the `NUMERIC` size you've given it'll produce an error before your `CHECK` constraint ever runs.