# Postgresql ERROR: operator does not exist: date ~~ unknown

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I do this query, I have no problems:

```
SELECT a.value, b.label AS campo, 'date' AS tipo
FROM contenido.field_value_textarea a 
JOIN estructura.field b ON a.field=b.id 
WHERE a.value LIKE '%aaa%'
```

contenido.field_value_textarea is `character varying(2000)`

But if I try to select from:

contenido.field_value_fecha which type is `date` I got this error message:

ERROR: operator does not exist: date ~~ unknown

What I'm trying to do is searching between different tables, each query select FROM it's table. Some tables use text values, textarea values, integer values, and it works, but when the value is `date` all fails. What can I do?

EDIT: By the way, my date values are like this: 2009-05-01

Comment: Can you show us the SQL that is generating the error, and the schema of the table?

Comment: Arghhhh, I got it, I had to CAST my date values as TEXT then LIKE as the given text. I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849071/error-operator-does-not-exist-numeric-unknown sorry

Comment: Using text matching on date values sounds error-prone to me. You might be better off using some of the [postgres date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). I'm thinking particularly of `date_trunc` and `date_part`.

Comment: Ok, I will see what can I do there. Those queries weren't meant to be used with dates, I had to add a search for dates too, so I was trying to reproduce the queries but in date.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `~~` operator is actually the [`LIKE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE).

You are trying to use an expression that looks like:

```
contenido.field_value_fecha.value LIKE '%aaaa%'
```

That is, you're trying to compare a date with a string (which, without the adequate context, is considered to be of type 'unknown'), and decide if the date looks like something.

If you actually want to do such a comparison, you need to convert the date to a string, which can be done by means of:

```
contenido.field_value_fecha.value::text LIKE '%aaaa%'
```

or (using standard SQL):

```
CAST(contenido.field_value_fecha.value AS text) LIKE '%aaaa%'
```

This will be syntactically correct... Whether it is meaningful or not, is a different part of the story.

Comment: Hey, much better than my solution: `WHERE CAST(a.value AS TEXT) LIKE '%aaa%'` . Now I did it like you said: `WHERE a.value::text LIKE '%aaa%' ` and it works ok too. Thanks!

Comment: @pmirnd `cast(a.value as text)` and `a.value::text` are the same thing but `::` is PostgreSQL-specific whereas `cast(...)` is standard SQL.